# Rails Convert UNIX timestamp to SQL DateTime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

I have timestamp as "1432927800000"

I want to save it in DateTime column of MySQL. (SQL DateTime column stores date in this format : `2010-06-24 11:30:00`)

I have tried

```
uTime = params[:fromDate] #contains "1432927800000"
Date.new(uTime).to_formatted_s(:db) #Comparison of String with 0 failed.
DateTime.strptime("1318996912",'%s') #Give weird date: Wed, 03 Sep 47377 12:00:00 +0000
Date.parse(uTime).to_s(:db) #Invalid Date
```

I am expecting `2015-5-30 1:00:00` from "1432927800000"

Comment: I have added the answer please check.

Comment: your expected resul is `"2015-05-30 01:00:00"` but `.to_s(:db)` is returns `"2015-05-29 22:30:00"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `strftime` will be better to use predefined `:db` [pattern](http://apidock.com/rails/Time/to_formatted_s) from ActiveSupport:

```
2.1.0 :002 > Time.at(1432927800000/1000).to_s(:db)
 => "2015-05-29 22:30:00"
```

`to_s` is alias for `to_formatted_s` method and defined in `Time` and `DateTime` classes.

Comment: webDev's expected resul is `"2015-05-30 01:00:00"` but `.to_s(:db)` is returns `"2015-05-29 22:30:00"`

Comment: @Amit this solutions looks like something which will work for multiple Databases... isn't it? I need to see why this returns time as 22:30:00 instead 01:00:00

Comment: I found some difference in what ActiveSupport returns and what sql returns. When In sql it is `2018-07-16 12:01:16.234121` but with `to_s(:db)` method `to_s(:db)` it changes to `2018-07-16 12:01:16`. Why the fraction is not coming with `to_s(:db)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this I Hope this will help you

I have tried it in my **Rails console** and I got following.

```
uTime = 1432927800000

Time.at(uTime/1000).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S")

## Output

"2015-05-30 01:00:00"
```

This a link where you which will helps you to convert unix timestamp 
http://www.epochconverter.com/